# Cannot find module 'tsconfig-paths/register'

Tags: typescript, npx, ts-node, tsconfig-paths

I'm trying to run a typescript script with ts-node in CLI, which means I don't have a package.json.

Here's the command I'm trying to run:

```
npx -p typescript@latest -p ts-node@latest -p @types/node@latest ts-node -T --project scripts/tsconfig.script.json scripts/my-script.ts
```

It works perfectly fine when I use relative paths inside the script.

Then I'm trying to enhance it by enabling paths from `tsconfig.script.json` in order to be able to import from them.

I want to use **tsconfig-paths** for it. Here're the command I'm trying to run:

```
npx -p typescript@latest -p ts-node@latest -p @types/node@latest -p tsconfig-paths@latest ts-node -T -r tsconfig-paths/register --project scripts/tsconfig.script.json scripts/my-script.ts
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tsconfig-paths/register'
```

I've tried to play around with order of arguments of `ts-node` as well as adding/removing options, however, I still cannot make it work and see the `tsconfig-paths` package.

Am I missing smth?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17):

I ran `npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths` and that error went away.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have that package installed, and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your node version, you can add the following key to your `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
  "^16.15.0"
}
```

This should fix the issue without requiring to install `tsconfig-paths`.

Comment: Why? HOW does adding this setting MAKE the problem go away?